# tor and private proxy still not enough

Tags: network-configuration

I am connecting to a tor circuit from behind a private proxy server. All the websites I check are not able to determine my location, but I know that someone is able to identify me by the default content in the search window when I visit a particular website being personally relevant, despite me never entering anything in that search window on that browser.

How are they doing this?

Comment: Are you using the Tor Browser or another browser? If it is another browser, there is a good chance that you have a cookie that is identifying you. The same goes for if you are using additional addons. Finally, is the website seeing the IP from your exit node or are they seeing the IP of the proxy? If it is the proxy, then it probably never changes which means Tor is doing nothing for you at all except slowing your connection.

Comment: I'm using a tor browser